# How does RSS readers fetch various field values, Tag names varies with different domain and does not follow a standard set of keys?

Tags: java, json, rss, jsoup, rss-reader

I am trying to implement a RSS reader and when I try to fetch values of like image,URL,pubdate,guid,description,content,etc., these values comes in different key tags, and doesn’t have a standard set of keys. Currently I use Switch case with few common keys to get values, even though there are some feeds with different tag names. How can I solve this globally for all Feeds type without missing values?